# Stuck on a function with return in JS

Tags: javascript, function

I'm stuck on this part: 
 - Add a new function named dealAnotherCard that has a parameter named hand that receives either the player’s or the dealer’s hand. 

 - Call the drawCard function and add the returned card to the array in the hand parameter.

My code looks like this

```
function dealAnotherCard (hand){

    player = hand;
    drawCard()
    return player;
}
```

The player is the array with the player cards. Not sure if to add the return in the parameter of drawCard function or even how to do the other thing. I'll continue trying to figure this out but would be eternally grateful for any help.

Comment: Please explain your question a bit more to get the right answers

Comment: sorry but there's not much to explain sadly, I'm following instructions and all it says are those lines, to create a function where the parameter hand receives the players or dealers hands. my code clearly doesnt make it run so I'm doing it wrong,  completely confused about the drawcard and return part too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, call the `drawCard` and check if this is an array if so then use `push` and add it result

```js
function dealAnotherCard(hand) {
  let result = hand;
  let drawCardResult = drawCard();
  if (Array.isArray(drawCardResult) {
      result.push(drawCardResult)
      return player;
    } else {
      console.log('Result is not an array ')
    }
  }
```

Comment: that generated the error in console "array is not defined". on line 168 which is the if line.

Comment: @dux8 sorry for typo, try now

Comment: yea got the 'result is not an array'

Comment: also how would I go about giving the hand parameter the cards from the player or dealer array?